# Suddenly I have troubles plotting with python

Tags: arch-linux, python, gtk, qt

I have a code that I used yesterday to generate plots. Today, when I tried to use it (with the same input as yesterday), I get an error:

> QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.

There was an update to the system (arch linux) that I ran today that is probably related. Also, I have removed some xfce4 libraries from my machine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=99175&p=2). I have installed libgnomeui and now everything work.